# How we check the past record of the usage of Memory and CPU by JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I want to write an admin tool for a website. In which i want to show the memory usage and CPU usage of the website in a graph. I read somewhere that JVM writes these data in a dump file which MAT tool use to show the result. So my question is where JVM dump this file and at what rate.

Because i want to show on the graph the last 24 hour usage. So how we can capture this data.

Looking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing at the moment inherent in the JVM that will produce the stream of data you want. You could leave a profiler such as JVisualVM hooked up to your app, but that might also slow it down considerably (that said, for memory profiling it's not so bad... depends on the non-functional requirements of your app).

Two further options:

### Write your own code using MBean stuff

In a ScheduledExecutorService, run a periodic process that interrogates the JVM via the [MBean interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html). You can generate a heap dump that can be viewing in MAT.

### Use cron and jmap

You can also use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) to generate heap dumps and schedule that at the operating system level to run every once-in-a-while. This might be better if you don't want to, or can't, alter your code.

Comment: Jmap is looking more promising but it gives only the memory usage. I want the CPU usage also. Please help me for the same also.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you want historical data you must record this yourself. When you connect using VisualVM, you always start at the point you connected.

The MAT tool can be used to examine a heap dump.  It only works on a memory snapshot and is painful to use IMHO.